# Description not shown in Facebook ShareDialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-facebook

I am trying the ShareLinkContent  using the ShareDialog from Facebook in my Android App. Following is the code snippet I have used. I have the content title and the description as it is needed for the post. It is fine while is show in the mobile while I try to post it.But When I see the post in the facebook it is different. Hope it is picking it from the google play store.

Please help to resolve this s that I can see the description and the tilte that I have set it in the share dialog

```
@Override
public void facebookShare(String msg) {
    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=memory.game.collection.free"))
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://i67.tinypic.com/svl2qt.png"))
                .setContentTitle("Test ContentTitle")
                .setContentDescription("Test content Description")
                .build();

        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
    }

}
```

### While Posting from Mobile Device

[image]

### The Post shared in Facebook

[image]

Comment: There is no surefire way to predict how a story will end up looking (across different devices) at the time of sharing.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: no. used open graph

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's [publish_actions permissions reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-publish_actions) states that it's **not** allowed to:

> Pre-fill the user message parameter with any content the user didn't
>   enter themselves, even if they can edit or delete that content before
>   sharing. This applies to posts, comments, photo captions, and photo
>   album captions.

I guess they decided to block the title and description parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is delayed answer. I have been through this recently and found out that it is not possible, even if its possible by any means, its not with [Facebook Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/). And specifically this [policy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill).

Even when you do go to declaration, I got this

> /**
>            * Sets the user generated caption for the photo. Note that the 'caption' must come from
>            * the user, as pre-filled content is forbidden by the Platform Policies (2.3).
>            *
>            * @param caption {@link java.lang.String} of a {@link com.facebook.share.model.SharePhoto}
>            * @return The builder.
>            */
>
> ```
>    public Builder setCaption(@Nullable final String caption) {
>         this.caption = caption;
>         return this;
>     }
> ```