# No image and content in preview when sharing Facebook app link for mobile only content

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sharer

When I try to implement the sharing of links for the app links using the `ShareDialog` using `ShareLinkContent`, the image and title are not shown correctly when the actually the post is shared.

```
String url = "https://fb.me/" + id; //Id is generated by app links hosting api
ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(activity);
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
    ShareLinkContent.Builder linkContentBuilder = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(url))
        .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
        .setContentDescription(contentDescription);
    if (imageUrl != null) {
        linkContentBuilder.setImageUrl(Uri.parse(imageUrl));
    }
    ShareLinkContent linkContent = linkContentBuilder.build();
    shareDialog.setShouldFailOnDataError(true);
    shareDialog.registerCallback(activity.callbackManager,
                                 new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Facebook sharing successful");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Facebook sharing cancelled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Facebook sharing error");
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    });
    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
}
```

But the sharing looks like below:

[Facebook sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEyej.png)

Can someone help me out?

Comment: where do you get stucked.?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan: the preview gets posted but the title and image are not coming what I give in `ShareDialog` (rather I think its trying to pickup from the url) but when I use graph api then I am getting correct title and image.

Comment: Are you using Facebook SDK to share photo. Are you using photo builder for sharing. Try using Share Link build.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33716721/2603965